# NPEs trying to get MethodDefinitions out of ClassDefinitions; how to diagnose?

Tags: java, intersystems-cache

Environment:

- the caché server is a x86_64 SuSE Linux Enterprise server; installation is, as far as I can tell, some 2014.x version;
- I have SSH access to the machine, but nothing web (VPN, ya know);
- the client side is a Debian Jessie machine;
- the client code is written in Java, using cachedb.jar version 2015.2.

What I'm doing is writing a SonarQube plugin for ObjectScript, and it works pretty well... Except when it does not.

What I do is separate all `ClientMethod`s with langauge JavaScript into their own files so that the SonarQube JS plugin can analyze them, and for this I use this method to collect the relevant methods:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List<MethodDefinition> readJsMethods(final boolean ignoreFailures)
    throws CacheException
{
    final Map<String, MethodDefinition> map;
    try {
        map = classDef.getMethods(); // classDef is a ClassDefiniton
    } catch (CacheException e) {
        if (ignoreFailures) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to obtain methods for class {}, ignored",
                className);
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        throw e;
    }

    final List<MethodDefinition> ret = new ArrayList<>();

    MethodDefinition definition;
    boolean failure = false;

    for (final Map.Entry<String, MethodDefinition> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        definition = entry.getValue();
        if (definition == null) { // <-- PROBLEM HERE
            LOGGER.error("Null method definition! Class {}, key {}",
                className, entry.getKey());
            if (ignoreFailures) {
                LOGGER.warn("Failures are ignored; returning no methods");
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }
            failure = true;
            continue;
        }
        if ("javascript".equalsIgnoreCase(definition.getLanguage()))
            ret.add(definition);
    }

    if (failure)
        throw new SqcaException("one or more method definitions are null"
            + " for class " + className);

    Collections.sort(ret, Comparator.comparing(BY_SEQUENCE));
    return ret;
}
```

At the line marked `// <-- PROBLEM HERE` it can happen that the definitions is indeed null. What is more, the exact ClassDefinition and key of the Map are *never the same* from one run to the other.

I have tried both to restart the Caché server and the whole VM (I do have root access) but the result doesn't change.

I suspect this is a problem on the server side but I have no idea how to diagnose it and, more importantly, how to fix it. And this code has worked flawlessly for several weeks before failing all of a sudden... And when it starts failing it will always fail, always at some random method in some random class...

How do I diagnose this, knowing that I don't have any access to the Caché web management portal at all?

---

Sample stack trace:

```
Jul 27, 2015 7:03:57 AM com.roche.sqca.read.Main main
INFO: Loading properties from sqca.properties
Jul 27, 2015 7:03:58 AM com.roche.sqca.read.CacheDbReader getAllClasses
INFO: Reading list of classes from database

Jul 27, 2015 7:04:27 AM com.roche.sqca.read.CacheDbReader getAllClasses
INFO: Result: 12296 total classes, 6920 included, 5376 excluded
Jul 27, 2015 7:04:27 AM com.roche.sqca.read.CosSourceWriter processClasses
INFO: Writing COS class files (directory: /home/sonar/.jenkins/jobs/Infinity/workspace)

Jul 27, 2015 7:04:57 AM com.roche.sqca.read.JsSourceWriter processClasses
INFO: Writing JavaScript client methods, if any (directory: /home/sonar/.jenkins/jobs/Infinity/workspace)

Jul 27, 2015 7:06:23 AM com.roche.sqca.read.CosClass readJsMethods
SEVERE: Null method definition! Class LISPages.WorkArea.Monitoring, key 19
Exception in thread "main" com.roche.sqca.read.SqcaException: one or more method definitions are null for class LISPages.WorkArea.Monitoring
    at com.roche.sqca.read.CosClass.readJsMethods(CosClass.java:199)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.CosClass.getJsMethods(CosClass.java:131)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.JsSourceWriter.processClasses(JsSourceWriter.java:96)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.Main.main(Main.java:142)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

And here is a trace when I actually ignore failures (`ignoreFailures` in the code above is set to true):

```
Jul 29, 2015 8:38:10 AM com.roche.sqca.read.Main main
INFO: Loading properties from sqca.properties
Jul 29, 2015 8:38:11 AM com.roche.sqca.read.CacheDbReader getAllClasses
INFO: Reading list of classes from database
Jul 29, 2015 8:38:33 AM com.roche.sqca.read.CacheDbReader getAllClasses
INFO: Result: 12296 total classes, 6920 included, 5376 excluded
Jul 29, 2015 8:38:33 AM com.roche.sqca.read.CosSourceWriter processClasses
INFO: Writing COS class files (directory: /home/sonar/.jenkins/jobs/Infinity/workspace)
Jul 29, 2015 8:39:03 AM com.roche.sqca.read.JsSourceWriter processClasses
INFO: Writing JavaScript client methods, if any (directory: /home/sonar/.jenkins/jobs/Infinity/workspace)
Jul 29, 2015 8:40:17 AM com.roche.sqca.read.CosClass readJsMethods
SEVERE: Null method definition! Class LISPages.WorkArea.Monitoring, key 109
Jul 29, 2015 8:40:17 AM com.roche.sqca.read.CosClass readJsMethods
WARNING: Failures are ignored; returning no methods
# 4 other similar messages for other classes.
# And them, BOOM:
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Message Count (452); expected: 95590 got: 1163022164. Connection closed
    at com.intersys.jdbc.InStream.invalidMessageReceived(InStream.java:308)
    at com.intersys.jdbc.InStream.checkHeader(InStream.java:108)
    at com.intersys.jdbc.InStream.readHeader(InStream.java:147)
    at com.intersys.jdbc.CacheConnection.sendCustomMessage(CacheConnection.java:1404)
    at com.intersys.cache.jbind.CustomMsgDBAdapter.sendCustomMessage(CustomMsgDBAdapter.java:922)
    at com.intersys.cache.jbind.CustomMsgDBAdapter.getObjectArrayElements(CustomMsgDBAdapter.java:655)
    at com.intersys.cache.jbind.JBindDatabase.getObjectArrayBuffer(JBindDatabase.java:632)
    at com.intersys.classes.ObjectArrayBuffer.getArrayBuffer(ArrayOfObjects.java:296)
    at com.intersys.classes.ArrayBuffer.load(ArrayBuffer.java:407)
    at com.intersys.classes.ArrayBuffer.getNext(ArrayBuffer.java:199)
    at com.intersys.classes.ArrayBuffer._getNext(ArrayBuffer.java:568)
    at com.intersys.classes.AbstractCacheArray._getNext(AbstractCacheArray.java:465)
    at com.intersys.classes.AbstractCacheArray._getFirst(AbstractCacheArray.java:455)
    at com.intersys.classes.AbstractCacheArray$EntryIterator.<init>(AbstractCacheArray.java:153)
    at com.intersys.classes.AbstractCacheArray$EntrySet.iterator(AbstractCacheArray.java:239)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.CosClass.readJsMethods(CosClass.java:182)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.CosClass.getJsMethods(CosClass.java:131)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.JsSourceWriter.processClasses(JsSourceWriter.java:96)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.Main.main(Main.java:142)
com.intersys.objects.CacheServerException: Failed to get elements of array with oref 57323 caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Message Count (452); expected: 95590 got: 1163022164. Connection closedUnderlying exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Message Count (452); expected: 95590 got: 1163022164. Connection closed

    at com.intersys.cache.jbind.CustomMsgDBAdapter.getObjectArrayElements(CustomMsgDBAdapter.java:660)
    at com.intersys.cache.jbind.JBindDatabase.getObjectArrayBuffer(JBindDatabase.java:632)
    at com.intersys.classes.ObjectArrayBuffer.getArrayBuffer(ArrayOfObjects.java:296)
    at com.intersys.classes.ArrayBuffer.load(ArrayBuffer.java:407)
    at com.intersys.classes.ArrayBuffer.getNext(ArrayBuffer.java:199)
    at com.intersys.classes.ArrayBuffer._getNext(ArrayBuffer.java:568)
    at com.intersys.classes.AbstractCacheArray._getNext(AbstractCacheArray.java:465)
    at com.intersys.classes.AbstractCacheArray._getFirst(AbstractCacheArray.java:455)
    at com.intersys.classes.AbstractCacheArray$EntryIterator.<init>(AbstractCacheArray.java:153)
    at com.intersys.classes.AbstractCacheArray$EntrySet.iterator(AbstractCacheArray.java:239)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.CosClass.readJsMethods(CosClass.java:182)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.CosClass.getJsMethods(CosClass.java:131)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.JsSourceWriter.processClasses(JsSourceWriter.java:96)
    at com.roche.sqca.read.Main.main(Main.java:142)
```

Comment: Is there an exception thrown? Can you add the complete exception including stacktrace?

Comment: @Konrad added an example; I'll do another run with failures ignored, this can give some strange exceptions as well...

Comment: From the code this line `map = classDef.getMethods();` produces a `map` with a NULL as value for key 19. You should check the `getMethods()` method.

Comment: @Konrad that's cachedb.jar code... See edit, I have added another output where I _try_ and ignore failures. To no avail :(

Comment: It is low-level error in jdbc connection, you can add logfile, and see dump with error, so format of jdbc string: 
`jdbc:Cache://<machine>:<port>/<namespace>/<logfile>:<eventclass>:<nodelay>:<ssl>`[documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BGJD_connecting#BGJD_C125815)